# How to response to full screen button in websites that has videos

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-view, android-video-player

I use webview to play videos from varios sites, some of them have a full screen button

[image]

I would like the webview to respond to the full screen button.

If I set `webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(false);` then video get stuck when clicking the full screen button and I can see the following error on the logcat:

```
10-09 08:32:27.970: D/gralloc(31814): unmmap  pid(1876), vaddr(0x589dc000)
10-09 08:32:27.970: E/gralloc(31814): [GR_MD] unmapping from 0x5786c000, size=33427456
10-09 08:32:27.970: D/gralloc(31814): unmmap  pid(1876), vaddr(0x5a9fb000)
10-09 08:32:27.970: E/gralloc(31814): [GR_MD] unmapping from 0x5984d000, size=33427456
10-09 08:32:27.975: D/gralloc(31814): unmmap  pid(1876), vaddr(0x5e616000)
10-09 08:32:27.975: E/gralloc(31814): [GR_MD] unmapping from 0x5d42a000, size=33427456
```

I'm using Android 4.0.1, here is my code:

```
setWebViewSettings(mVideoWebView);
String data_html = "<!DOCTYPE HTML> <html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xmlns:og=\"http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/\" xmlns:fb=\"http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml\"> <head></head> <body style=\"margin:0 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 0;\"> <iframe src=\"http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/xu4vre\" width=\"300\" height=\"162"\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe> </body> </html> ";
mVideoWebView.loadData(data_html, "text/html", null);


public static void setWebViewSettings(WebView webview) {
    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(false); // zoom y/n
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true); // true = like desktop
    webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);

    //webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    //webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    //webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: what is the version of the device you testing on? Does your application crashes when you test it on devices higher than ICS?

Comment: I use Galaxy s2 runnnyng Cyanogen Android 4.0.1. The application doesn't crash, just the webview stop responding.

Comment: add webSettings.setWebChromeClient( new WebChromeClient()); and test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12850816/475472

I had to create a new `WebChromeClient`, overriding `onShowCustomView(View view, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback)` and `onHideCustomView()`