# All videos(YouTube) not loading in Web View in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, webview, youtube

I wanted to add **all youtube videos in a channel** in android app.So I created web view in Android Studio and I added Youtube channel link to as url.But **all the channel videos not loading** after running app.Why is that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [YouTube Video not playing in WebView - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708890/youtube-video-not-playing-in-webview-android)

Comment: Thank you for reply.Nope..my question is different one.