# Youtube videos shown black screen in webView when click on play buttonn

Tags: android, xamarin, android-videoview

```
        var webView = (WebView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.JackKnifeVid);
        WebSettings settings = webView.Settings;
        settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        webView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.LoadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWOZyf8kaH0");
```

It only plays a video but showing a black screen.

Comment: Can you try this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422427/android-webview-slow ? The reason you are seeing black screen, could be because of low webView performance

Comment: I checked the same code code with yours on Android 9.0. It works well. Could you provide more details for me to reproduce?

Answer (score 0):

Hi my friend use this before load content

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {});
```

and you can see this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708890/youtube-video-not-playing-in-webview-android)

Comment: Its going directly to youtube app

Comment: thats why i used setWebViewClient it stops going to youtube app, but then its black screen

Comment: var webView = (WebView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.JackKnifeVid);
        WebSettings settings = webView.Settings;
        settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        webView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {});
        webView.LoadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWOZyf8kaH0");

Comment: its now blank white HAHAHA

Comment: XD, I posted another answer please check it